# C++14 My program is not returning what is expected

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    //You are in the elevator now;

    //Define variables;
    char a;
    char b;

    //Ask questions;
    printf("You are in the elevator now.\nPlease enter which floor you want to visit?\nPress 'L' for Basement, '1' for 1st floor, '2' for 2nd floor, and '3' for 3rd floor:\n");
    scanf("%c", &a);

    //Display options;
    if (a=='L'){
        printf("You are at the basement now.\n", a);

    scanf("%c", &b);
      printf("Where do you want to go?\nOnly Option is 'P' for Parking lot:\n");

         else (b=='P')

          printf("You are in the Parking Lot now.\n", b);
    }  

    else if (a=='1')
        printf("You are at the main floor now.\n", a);

    else if (a=='2')
        printf("You are at the Mechanical Department now.\n", a);

    else if (a=='3')
        printf("You are at the Electrical Department now.\n", a);

    else{
        printf("It's not an option\n");
    }

}
```

For the first option L after the user selects P I am getting the command is not found. I should be getting You are in the parking Lot now. I am not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Am sorry I put the problem multiple times

Comment: I am having trouble with my computer

Comment: Why do you keep adding random edits?

Comment: Sorry the system wasn't let me upload the question

Comment: Your random indenting makes your code hard to read. The second `scanf` and the `printf` underneath it should be indented, and everything should be aligned.

Comment: Does this even compile? The brace-less `else` doesn't seem to have a matching `if`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it compiles but when I copy it here it mess it up, I have it align

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile though.

Comment: I tried everything and I am still getting command not found

Comment: I am using this website http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php because I don't have my computer with my sotware, and it does compile it

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
else (b==='P')
```

by

```
if (b == 'P')
```

Comment: Better yet, add curly braces as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check This CODE out...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//You are in the elevator now;
//Define variables;
char a;
char b;

//Ask questions;
printf("You are in the elevator now.\nPlease enter which floor you want to visit?\nPress 'L' for Basement, '1' for 1st floor, '2' for 2nd floor, and '3' for 3rd floor:\n");
scanf("%c", &a);

//Display options;
if (a=='L')
{
        printf("You are at the basement now.\n");
        printf("Where do you want to go?\nOnly Option is 'P' for Parking lot:\n");
        cin >> b;
        if (b=='P'){
        printf("You are in the Parking Lot now.\n");}
}

else if (a=='1')
    printf("You are at the main floor now.\n");

else if (a=='2')
    printf("You are at the Mechanical Department now.\n");

else if (a=='3')
    printf("You are at the Electrical Department now.\n");

else
    printf("It's not an option\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ Karthik Chowdary after the user puts in L and then P, the compiler shows P commands not found

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you're probably running into is that `scanf("%c")` only consumes a single character, and after you press enter you'll have a `'\n'` in the buffer. You'll probably want to get your input in some other way, such as using something like:

```
std::string command;
std::cin >> command;
if (command == "P") {
    // ...
}
```

since that will, by default, load an entire whitespace-delineated string in at once.

Answer (score -1):

You have three equals signs in your conditional statement.

b === 'P' instead of b == 'P'

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: I think the issue lies in the structure of your if block. If the user selects 'L', they have no choice but to opt for 'P' next; ergo, you don't need an else statement to test for b. Try a separate if statement.